# If $p$ divides a product $ab$ of integers, then $p$ divides $a$ or $p$ divides $b$, given $p$ is prime.

Tags: abstract-algebra, gcd-and-lcm

I'm sorry for the misleading title, my issue is not with the proof for the statement in the title but a step in the proof.

Suppose prime $p$ divides $ab$ but not $a$.

The only positive divisors of $p$ are $1$ and $p$ and $p$ does not divide a gcd$(1,p)=1$.

**Therefore $\exists$ integers $r$ and $s :ra+ps=1$.**(I do not follow this)

multiplying both sides by $b$ gives $rab+psb=b$

since $p$ divides $rab$ and $psb$, so $p$ divides $ab$.

The proof seems elementary but the statement in bold letters I don't seem to understand the reasoning to it.

Comment: Please consider the use of MathJAX and how I have applied it here; feel free to correct any misapplied adjustments as well...

Comment: That's called the Bezout identity. The gcd of any two integers $a$ and $b$ can be expressed that way in terms of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: This is a property of the gcd. If $\gcd(a,b)=d$ then there are some $k,l\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $ka+lb=d$. This property is even more important than the definition of the gcd. (actually, there are even equivalent definitions which involve that property)

Comment: so you mean the identity was merely applied to a and p and since gcd =1,ra+sp=1?